# How to "round" minutes and hours

Tags: iphone, math, clock

I did not really know on how to title this question so hopefully you've find the way in :)

My Problem is:
I wanted to set a clock time for a label with a UISlider.
So basically my slider min value is 0000 and the max value is 2400. (24 hour format)
So how do I achieve a properly formatted clock?

For example if my slider's value is at (1161)11:61 it should be (1201)12:01 and so on.
Any tipps for that :)

Would be great to get some help here.
Thanks to all who participate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you start from 0 to 1440. (24 hours = 1440 minutes) and do something like below.

```
int hours = slider.value / 60; -> no of hours;
int minutes = slider.value %60; -> no of minutes;    
NSString *clock = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d : %d", hours, minutes];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That would be much easier :-)

Comment: Pretty good, though it relies on the assumption that every day has 1440 minutes, which is a false assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an NSDateComponents object. Create one, then break up your slider value into two parts: the thousands and hundred digits become the hour, and the tens and ones digits become the minute. You can feed this object to an NSCalendar to transform it into an actual NSDate (if that's what you want).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That sounds interesting. I'll take a look at this approach, too!